# Helps plot the graph when the variable has equal values

Tags: r, nls

The code below generates a graph with dots and a "prediction" line, so to speak. In this case, it is generating for `dmda=01/07`. However, I cannot generate a graph for the day 02/07 or 03/07. From what I understand it is due to the values ​​of the variable `datas` being equal. For example, the variable `datas` for 01/07 is: 12, 12, 16 and 18 - in this case it generates the graph. For 02/07 it is 13, 13, 13 and for 03/07 is 11 and 11. Because these values ​​are equal, the `nls function` does not work. So what I would like to do is:

When the values ​​of the variable `datas` are equal, the code would not need to go through the `nls function`, but would generate the graph with the red dot being the value obtained by the variable `datas`, that is, if it is for 03/07, the graph would have the line of "predction" going to 11 same. I put an image to illustrate.

I appreciate any help!

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                 "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-04-02","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-03"),
       Week= c("Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Monday"),
       DR01 = c(14,11,14,13,13,14,0,0), DR02= c(14,12,16,17,13,12,0,0),DR03= c(19,15,14,13,13,12,0,0),
       DR04 = c(15,14,13,13,16,12,13,0),DR05 = c(15,14,15,13,16,12,13,11),
       DR06 = c(21,14,13,13,15,16,13,11),DR07 = c(12,15,14,14,19,14,13,11)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

dmda<-"2021-07-01"

datas<-df1 %>%
  filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(name = as.numeric(name))
colnames(datas)<-c("Days","Numbers")

dif <- as.Date(dmda) - as.Date(df1$date1[1]) + 1
datas <- datas[dif:max(datas$Days, na.rm = TRUE),]

plot(Numbers ~ Days, xlim=c(0,8), ylim=c(0,20), data = datas,xaxs='i')
mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0), data = datas)
new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
lines(new.data$Days, predict(mod, newdata=new.data))
points(0, coef(mod)[2], col="red", pch=19, cex=1.2, xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

**Example for 03/07**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is tough because your example isn't really *minimal*; there's a lot of other stuff going on. It looks like the real issue is that `nls()` won't work when all the input y-values are equal, but it's buried in a bunch of other stuff.

With that in mind, here are two options:

## With ggplot()

Here's a proposed simplified approach using `ggplot()`. It looks like you're trying to do three things:

1. Filter your dataframe to only look at specific row(s) for specific values of `date2`.
2. Pivot your results longer so that the values in columns `DR01`-`DR07` are put into new rows, with the row names in a column called `Days` and the values in a column called `Numbers`.
3. Remove any rows where `Numbers` equals zero.
4. Make a scatterplot of `Numbers` vs. `Days`.
5. Draw a line of best fit through the points on the scatterplot.

If that's what you're trying to do, here's some code that does it using your data for the day `2021-07-03`:

```
dmda<-"2021-07-03"

df1 %>%
  filter(date2 == dmda) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("DR"), 
               names_pattern = "DR(.+)", 
               names_to = "Days",
               values_to = "Numbers") %>%
  filter(Numbers != 0) %>%
  mutate(Days = as.numeric(Days)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=Days, y=Numbers)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=Days, y=Numbers),
              method = "lm",
              formula = "y ~ x",
              fullrange = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,8)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,20))
```

[image: A scatterplot made using ggplot().]

Note that I've set the plot's limits manually to match your images.

## With plot()

Here's a *minimal* example that uses `plot()` and a simple `if` to draw the plots in two cases:

1. Where the values of `Numbers` are different, and `nls()` will work; and
2. Where the values of `Numbers` are all the same, so `nls()` won't work.

I've skipped a bunch of steps to make it minimal but you will be able to apply this logic to your own real data.

```
################################
# test data with date identifier, Days column ranging from 1:7, and Numbers
# column for date a Numbers are random, for date b Numbers are all 11.
df <- tibble(date2 = c(rep("2021-07-01", 7), rep("2021-07-02", 7)),
             Days = c(1:7, 1:7),
             Numbers = c(sample(10:20, size = 7), rep(11,7)))

# choose the date of interest
dmda <- "2021-07-01"

# get our data subset
df2 <- df %>%
  filter(date2 == dmda) %>%
  filter(Numbers > 0)

# get a set of Days values to generate model predictions
predict_days <- tibble(Days = seq(0, max(df2$Days), len = 45))

# plot the observed points
plot (x = df2$Days, 
      y = df2$Numbers,
      xlim = c(0,8),
      ylim = c(0,20))

if (length(unique(df2$Numbers)) > 1) {
  # fit a model to our data subset
  mod <- nls(data = df2,
             formula = Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,
             start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0))
  
  # draw the fit line
  lines(predict_days$Days, predict(mod, newdata = predict_days))
  
  # set up the y value for the point
  y_point <- coef(mod)[2]
}

if (length(unique(df2$Numbers == 1))){
  # draw a horizontal line through all the values
  lines(predict_days$Days,
        rep(unique(df2$Numbers), length(predict_days$Days)))
  
  # set up the y value for the point
  y_point <- unique(df2$Numbers)
}

points(0, y_point, col="red", pch=19, cex=1.2, xpd=TRUE)
```

This gives an answer like you're looking for:

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thanks for reply! It be possible to do without using ggplot? To make the image as I did?

Comment: Check the edit, it should do what you want. In future also read about [making a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) which makes it much easier to help you.